# Website design using html and php(no javascript/jquery/ajax)

Tags: php, css, html

I am new to website designing, 
and i am starting with building webapplication for my small cd database. I have four div on my page Header
     nav
     content
     footer
in my nav i have menu links clicking on them will change the content in content div, but i am having trouble loading a new content in same div upon selecting a dropdownn menu 
for eg: Search link in nav should display dropdown menu in content and selected value is 1 then php shld run Select query taking id in where clause and dropdown button should hide and div content should display a table based on query.

Please help i am really stuck i know it can be done with Javascript, but i have no knowledge in javascript although its similar to java, but i am trying to use html css and php.

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: It cannot be done via PHP (alone). PHP will executed when the page is loaded and so you cannot make any changes without loading the page again.

Comment: If you really want to do it the hard way ( without javascript ) you'll have to make use of forms ( POST or GET ) or links that make use of GET and submit the page each time for a reload, as php is server side processing.

Comment: JavaScript is not particularly similar to Java except that it's also a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't like using to javascript you can try to change you structure of php like :
home.php :

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'menu.php';
    include 'content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

in header.php : a banner or logo with text.
in menu.php : your links like

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="./home.php">Home</a><br/>';
    echo '<a href="./home.php?m=1">About</a><br/>';
    echo '<a href="./home.php?m=2">Products</a><br/>';
    echo '<a href="./home.php?m=3">Services</a><br/>';
    echo '<a href="./home.php?m=4">Contact</a><br/>';
?>
```

in content.php:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_GET['m'])) $_GET['m']=0;

   switch($_GET['m']){
       case 0:
       include 'page_0.php';
       break;
       case 1:
       include 'page_1.php';
       break;
       case 2:
       include 'page_2.php';
       break;
       case 3:
       include 'page_3.php';
       break;
       case 4:
       include 'page_4.php';
       break;

   }
?>
```

so you need to create all thèses page_0.php ... page_4.php

hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is place another div inside the div you already have, give it an id of content1 or something.

Then change the display property when you click a link

```
<script>
document.getElementById("content1").style.display = 'block'; would display the div
document.getElementById("content1").style.display = 'none'; would hide the div
</script>
```

This would be the easiest way to do it, you can also use CSS, you really can't do it with HTML, and PHP isn't use for stuff like that.