# Set up a HTML page with left and right panel

Tags: javascript, css, html

how can I set up a HTML Page with two content sides? Without `<frames>` !

In example:

On the left side should be the menu for the navigation.
On the right side should be the content of the page.

Example menu:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="menuleftcontent">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li> <a href="showfirstcontent">first</a></li>
            <li><a href="showsecondcontent">second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="firstcontent">first</div>
        <div id="secondcontent">second</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The menu on the left side should be a fix content and the right content should be changeable.

I have made a sketch:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for the handdrawn picture though.

Comment: your html is correct, now you just have to apply css

Comment: Have you, at the very least, read the A List Apart article "[In Search of the Holy Grail](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)"? Did it not work, how did it fail, what problems did you have implementing it?

Comment: to have a dynamic content I already leave an exlanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176546/website-design-using-html-and-phpno-javascript-jquery-ajax/20176750#20176750

Comment: Something like this may be: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: @Salman A yes something like that. An this combined with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5dGA8/5/)

Comment: @mpears: see revised answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-arrange the code so that (i) main content appears before sidebar in HTML source order (ii) add a clearing div (iii) change the `href` attribute of menu links:

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="firstcontent">firstcontent</div>
        <div id="secondcontent">secondcontent</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuleftcontent">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#firstcontent">first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#secondcontent">second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="clearingdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```css
#page {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#maincontent {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
#menuleftcontent{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#clearingdiv {
    clear: both;
}
```

For the obscure part of your question, you need to use JavaScript to show/hide divs. While it is possible to use vanilla JavaScript, the jQuery library makes it much easier:

```javascript
$(function () {
    $("#maincontent > div:gt(0)").hide();
    $("#menu a").on("click", function (e) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#maincontent > " + href).show();
        $("#maincontent > :not(" + href + ")").hide();
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/5dGA8/7/)

Comment: Ok, but the problem is both contents appears at the same time. How can I set up, in example onpageload the firstcontent appears and when I click on the second menu button the secondcontent appears and the old content (firstcontent) disappears.

Comment: Perfect! That work's great. If you can tell me now how your example work's with [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) in example I click on "reports" and a new empty page appears then you are made my day!!!

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery so the above code should work as-is (I am not exactly sure what you are asking).

Comment: It's hard to explain... [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) looks good. On the left side is the menu and on the right side the content. When I click on"reports" then on the right it should be appears in example "hello" and when I click on "overview" it should be appears "byebye".... How can i realize that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to split page vertically without frames. There is an answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/11662564/841037

If you are finding a solution to make every page have the fixed content on the left. Then you may seek for something called page template or master page in your backend web framework.

Answer (score 0):

just apply some css to your html like this :

```
#page{
    width: 1280px;
    display: inline;
}

#menuleftcontent{
    float: left;
    width: 420px;
}

#maincontent{
    float: left;
    width: 960px;    
}
```

width are some example ;)

Comment: you can use % instead of px to have an extensible style :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how you can implement splitting your contents. Although, there are many ways to do this actually :)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGPp4/1/)

```
#page {
    width: 100%;
}

#menuleftcontent {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

#maincontent {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below css for your html to display it in left and right frame structure

```
    #menuleftcontent
    {
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
    }

    #maincontent
   {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;    
    }

   #page
   {
        width : 100%;
        clear : both;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best you can do is make 2 divs. One with `float: left`, give that a fixed width, and then create another with a `margin-left` with the same width as your menu.

CSS:

```
#leftie {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

#rightie {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="leftie">
    This is your menu
</div>

<div id="rightie">
    This is your main content
</div>
```

Working example:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/xynw4/show/

Fiddle URL:
http://jsfiddle.net/xynw4/

Comment: margin-left !!! this is the bad way. if you use it you can't have an extensible style.

Comment: Please explain why `margin-left` is a bad way.

Comment: for good practics , you'd have a flexible layout with relative length. this help to have the best preview in :smartphones and tablets.

Comment: That's an argueable way of doing things. But using percentages on very small screens can be unreadable or broken (`overflow` isn't a wildcard), wich is the reason why a lot of frameworks don't use percentages, but set pixels depending on the screen dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

here is an exemple of CSS to style your HTML :

```
  <style>
       .page{width:100%; min-height:900px;}
       .menuleftcontent{min-width:20%;float:left;height:900px;border:dotted 1px red;}
       .maincontent{min-width:78%;float:left;height:900px;border:dotted 1px blue;}
    </style>



<div id="page" class="page">   
    <div id="menuleftcontent" class="menuleftcontent">
        <ul id="menu">
                       <li><a href="showfirstcontent" </a>first</li>
                        <li><a href="showsecondcontent" >second</a></li>

        </ul> 
    </div> 
    <div id="maincontent" class="maincontent">   
         <div id="firstcontent" >first</div>

         <div id="secondcontent">second</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```